# EPI Server website build using ASP.Net MVC is not accessible outside edit mode

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I have created a ASP.Net MVC application using the EI Server template provided in Visual Studio. The only page I have created is showing in the Edit mode. But when i am trying to access it outside the  edit mode it is giving the error HTTP 404 . Please suggest what is the reason for this.

Thanks and Regards

Utpal Maity

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but it happened to a co-worker of mine. Did you publish the page?

Comment: @Andreas Yes I have published the page. But when i am running the MVC project from visual studio it is giving the 404 not found error.

Comment: My demo application is shared in the below link.                                 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8WbuWmb0H2aeHNCSkVXY2xNems/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi,The problem is solved. i have a problem in specifying the url.